# Desabilitar campo se outro estiver preenchido

Tags: php, javascript

Preciso que: se o campo Código estiver vazio o campo Código Interno pode ficar habilitado / vazio também, e se o campo código for preenchido o campo código interno tem que ser desabilitado (pois ao informar o código o código interno é preenchido automaticamente).

Mas meu código esta fazendo ao contrário, só habilita o campo código interno após o código estar preenchido. E outra, preciso tratar o erro de caso o usuário insira um valor no campo Código e retire o valor o campo Código interno volte a ser disabled imediatamente, tem essa possibilidade ?

```html
    <script type="text/javascript">
var codigo = document.getElementById("codigo"); 
var codigo_interno = document.getElementById("codigo_interno");


codigo.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
    codigo_interno.disabled = codigo.value.trim().length > 0;
});

  //agora uma função para keyup muito semelhante para o codigo_interno
codigo_interno.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
    codigo.disabled = codigo_interno.value.trim().length > 0;
});
</script>

<label>Código</label>
<input type="text" id="codigo">

<label>Código Interno</label>
<input type="text" id="codigo_interno">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode simplificar a lógica que está a utilizar para uma atribuição direta, com base na comparação da quantidade de carateres escritos no `codigo`. Consegue saber a quantidade de carateres acedendo a `length` do `value` do campo:

```
codigo_interno.disabled = codigo.value.length > 0;
```

Assim fica com `disabled` a verdeiro caso o tamanho seja maior que 0 e a falso caso contrário. Pode até evitar possíveis espaços inadvertidos no inicio e no fim chamando utilizando a função `trim` para os cortar:

```
codigo_interno.disabled = codigo.value.trim().length > 0;
```

Aconselho também a utilizar o evento `onkeyup`, para que seja mais interativo e mude à medida que o usuário preenche, e que faça o registo desse evento através de Javascript para organizar melhor.

Exemplo:

```js
var codigo = document.getElementById("codigo");
var codigo_interno = document.getElementById("codigo_interno");

codigo.addEventListener('keyup', function() {//registo  é feito com addEventListener
  codigo_interno.disabled = codigo.value.trim().length > 0;
});
```

```html
<label>Código</label>
<input type="text" id="codigo">

<label>Código Interno</label>
<input type="text" id="codigo_interno">
```

Note que coloquei a busca dos campos html com `getElementById` fora da função pois assim é apenas feita uma vez.

**Edit**:

Se precisar que os campos sejam utilizados em alternativa, ou seja, escrevendo num desativa o outro e vice-versa, basta aplicar uma função idêntica ao campo `codigo_interno`. Essa função irá desativar o campo `codigo` se tiver careteres escritos em `codigo_interno`:

```js
var codigo = document.getElementById("codigo");
var codigo_interno = document.getElementById("codigo_interno");

codigo.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
  codigo_interno.disabled = codigo.value.trim().length > 0;
});

//agora uma função para keyup muito semelhante para o codigo_interno
codigo_interno.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
  codigo.disabled = codigo_interno.value.trim().length > 0;
});
```

```html
<label>Código</label>
<input type="text" id="codigo">

<label>Código Interno</label>
<input type="text" id="codigo_interno">
```

Comment: parabens, vc habilitou e desabilitou, mas  no caso ele precisa que se um estiver preenchido o outro desabilite, ai vc está habilitando e desabilidando apenas um campo

Comment: @MarcosBrinner Não foi o que eu percebi pela pergunta. Está a dizer que se escrever no `codigo` desativa o `codigo_interno`, mas se escrever no `codigo_interno` desativa o `codigo` é isso ?

Comment: Correto, ele quer que se um campo independente de qual for esteja escrito desabilite o outro

Comment: @MarcosBrinner Veja a minha edição e confirme se é esse o resultado esperado.

Comment: Sim, agora está funcionando como ele solicitou :) já te dei um up ai!

Comment: comigo não funcionou, editei o código na pergunta para mostrar como esta

Comment: @VictorT. Sem a função `libera`. Repare que ela não existe no meu exemplo, pois eu faço a atribuição diretamente no Javascript

Comment: Vou editar novamente, eu estou tentando sem a função em cima mesmo

Comment: @VictorT. O problema agora tem a ver com o executar do código antes do html ter sido gerado. O snippet do StackOverFlow garante que o JS é executado depois do html se separar o html na area do html e o JS na area do JS. No código que tem neste momento pode resolver o problema de uma de duas maneiras: 1) Passar o JS para o fim de `<body>`. 2) Colocar o JS todo dentro de uma função e chamar essa função no atributo `onload` do `<body>`

Comment: obrigado funcionou

Answer (score 1):

No seu código já estava setado para o `input` **codigo_interno** ficar desabilitado, dessa forma o mesmo não mudaria o status pois você queria mudar para um estado que já estava setado.

```js
document.getElementById("codigo").onblur = function() {libera()};
function libera() {
  var codigo = document.getElementById("codigo");
  var codigo_interno = document.getElementById("codigo_interno");

  if (codigo !== "") {
    codigo_interno.disabled = true;
    codigo_interno.value = "produto...";
  }
}
```

```html
<label for="codigo">Código
<input type="text" id="codigo">
</label>
<label for="codigo_interno">Código Interno
<input type="text" id="codigo_interno">
</label>
```

Answer (score -2):

apenas modifique:

```
if(codigo != ""){
    codigo_interno.disabled = false;
}
```

por

```
if(codigo != ""){
    codigo_interno.disable = false;
}
```

a propriedade esta errada, apenas erro de digitação

Comment: o parametro é o disabled mesmo, porem ele está verificando  se  o  valor é vasio, ao invés de verificar o streng do campo

Comment: -1, é `disabled` é uma propriedade mais que valida num elemento html. Confirme por si mesmo na [documentação do MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/disabled)